# Magento & migration & PDOException

Tags: mysql, magento, exception, pdo, magento2

I have a bug when I try to migrate magento (many other too but fixed), for this one I don't know how to see more info :

```
[INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
22% [======>---------------------] Remaining Time: 1 sec

 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '0' pour la clef 'PRIMARY'
```

I just want something to show more infos about this exception like the table name and the raw query ! This kind of exception without the table name is... useless.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Maybe the full trace has been dumped there. You could also try turning up verbosity and seeing if that gives you more data (`-vvv`)

Comment: with -vvv I have stack trace but not the query, I think that I should modify the Adapter/Mysql.php class to output the query